# How could this has cycle dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

When launching my java application, I got the following errors:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  securityConfiguration
└──<-──┘
```

Although the log is vivid, I still don't understand how SecurityConfiguration has cycle bean dependencies.

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to easily paste the codes of SecurityConfiguration, so here they are: https://gist.github.com/blackmonkey/615232845025663597a2ba5f711caff5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot 2.6.0 Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254555/spring-boot-2-6-0-error-creating-bean-with-name-websecurityconfig)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Henning! It does answer my question. Please add you answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the password encoder. It is required to build the auto-configured beans that you are injecting in the contructor of the class.

You can break the cycle by making the bean factory method static:

```
@Bean
public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

This make it clear to Spring that the encoder does not depend on anything injected into the class instance.