# Relying upon circular reference is discouraged and they are prohibited, by default, in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting below error message when I am running my spring boot application.

```
Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfiguration (field private com.prity.springbootdemo1.service.UserService com.prity.springbootdemo1.config.SecurityConfiguration.userService)
↑     ↓
|  userServiceImpl (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder com.prity.springbootdemo1.service.UserServiceImpl.passwordEncoder)
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Comment: Fix your code to not need a circular dependency. Apparently you have your own `UserService`, which propably also acts as a `UserDetailsService` which you need in the configuration class. Which is a problem as that configuration class also creates the `PasswordEncoder` you  need. To fix remove the need of the circular dependency, I would suggest making a separate `UserDetailsService` which only does that and doesn' tneed the `PasswordEncoder`, for the rest you can use your `UserService` as is.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement in this way.

Comment: @pritysinha seeing you have circular reference with passwordEncoder and security configuration, I believe you will need the same solution as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527547/7237884 . This probably happened with update to spring boot 2.6.0

Answer (score 14):

You can try with this. Add it to file **application.properties**

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

And try to run. This is not best solution you still need to **find better way to fix problem**.

Answer (score 11):

So if you have a class `A` and you somehow run into this problem when injecting the class `A` into the constructor of class `B`, use the `@Lazy` annotation in the constructor of class `B`. This will break the cycle and inject the bean of `A` lazily into `B`. So, instead of fully initializing the bean, it will create a proxy to inject into the other bean. The injected bean will only be fully created when it's first needed.

```
@Component
public class CircularDependencyA {

    private CircularDependencyB circB;

    @Autowired
    public CircularDependencyA(@Lazy CircularDependencyB circB) {
        this.circB = circB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Constructor Injection just use the `@Autowired` annotation. and also add the following line in **resources/application.properties** file

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

**For example :**

[image: Example for using @Autowired]

Comment: Field-based autowiring is always a bad practice and only makes the code harder to test. Never, ever suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded your Spring Boot to 2.6.0 and later? Maybe you should modify your SecurityConfiguration. See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)

In my project, I did this. Finially, it works well.

```Java
import com.yourweb.filter.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;
import com.yourweb.security.AuthenticationEntryPointImpl;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsPasswordService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private AuthenticationEntryPointImpl authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Resource
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Resource
    private JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(
            HttpSecurity http,
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            UserDetailsPasswordService userDetailsPasswordService) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .userDetailsPasswordManager(userDetailsPasswordService)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>(15);
        encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/captcha").anonymous()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/*.html",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/profile/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/upload/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/common/download**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/*/api-docs").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/druid/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/modeler/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/process/general/read-resource/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/process/definition/resource/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/activiti/getTracePhoto/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/process/getTracePhoto/**").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/**/deviceFileMaintenance/addDeviceFileMaintenance").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/**/deviceFileInstall/addDeviceFileInstall").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/**/photoUpload").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue with the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(
            AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider,
            JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter
    ) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(
                        jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration configuration
    ) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
    ) {
        var daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

I then extracted the last three beans to a new class, with @Configuration annotation. It did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if a class B is `@Autowired` in class A , this means you are directly injecting dependency of class B into that class A. If this causing cyclic dependency, then remove the `@Autowired` Annotation and create a constructor and add `@Lazy` annotation in the input parameter. The constructor will add the dependency whenever it is required .

```java
class Dog{
    @Autowired 
    private Animal animal;
    .....
}

class Animal{
    .....
}
```

If this causing cyclic dependency, then

```java
class Dog{
    private Animal animal;
    public Dog(@Lazy Animal animal){
    return this.animal=animal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Explanation** (**note:** you don't really need to read this)

When dealing with circular dependencies in Spring, it's akin to having two friends, A and B, who rely on each other excessively. To resolve this, we can use the `@Lazy` annotation, instructing Spring to only create Friend B when Friend A explicitly needs it. Although this might introduce a slight delay the first time Friend B is requested, it helps break the cycle. It's important to be cautious about potential issues, especially in scenarios involving multiple dependencies. While there's a more potent solution with `spring.main.allow-circular-references`, it comes with risks and is not always advisable. By employing `@Lazy`, we can ensure our friends cooperate without causing any undue trouble.

The better solution depends on the specific context and requirements of your application. Using `@Lazy` is a more straightforward and often safer approach, as it defers the creation of the bean until it's actually needed, breaking the circular dependency. On the other hand, enabling `spring.main.allow-circular-references` is a more advanced option that might be suitable for specific scenarios but comes with potential **runtime issues**. It's crucial to assess the trade-offs and choose the solution that aligns with the design and stability goals of your application.

**Solution which worked well for me**

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
private BeanB beanB;
```

(**another silly note:** using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` with `@Lazy` , won't work)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

just add in your proprieties in  application.yml

spring:
main:
allow-circular-references: true