# Beans form a cycle

Tags: java, spring

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  webSecurityConfig defined in file [D:\OneDrive - Amity University\CODES\A User Authentication System\demo\target\classes\com\example\demo\security\WebSecurityConfig.class]
└──<-──┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
package com.example.demo.security;

import com.example.demo.appuser.AppUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public DefaultSecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

- I tried putting @lazy on one of the beans but it didnt work
- I tried Making one bean on other class then extending it with other but it didnt work
- tried putting circular ref true in yml file but it didnt work

Comment: why do you need to define those as variables and why do you need an all args constructor? It looks like its trying to init those beans but the beans dont exist yet because the construction of the object has not completed and theres your circular dependency

Comment: you can check this question, probably this fix your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71867218/relying-upon-circular-reference-is-discouraged-and-they-are-prohibited-by-defau

Comment: you can check this question, i hope it helps you:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71867218/relying-upon-circular-reference-is-discouraged-and-they-are-prohibited-by-defau)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your config depends on `bCryptPasswordEncoder`, and at the same time the config defines the password encoder bean. You need an instance of password encoder to create the config instance, but you need a config instance to create the password encoder.

Options:

1. Define password encoder bean in another configuration class, this will break the cycle.
2. Use the bean definition method to get the instance, not a field. If I remember correctly spring does some 'magic' and it will get the bean, not another instance.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

3. Use setter injection (not recommended, fixes symptom, not the cause).
4. Use field injection (not recommended, fixes symptom, not the cause).

Not related but you should define your bean as `PasswordEncoder`:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

There is no need to lock yourself in using single password encoder implementation.