# Issue for circular dependency Spring-context 5.3.9 to 5.3.13

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-context

I have updated my org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.9 to 5.3.13

and start getting issue for circular dependency.

My code look's like

````
```@Component("myMessageHandler")
public class MyMessageHandler {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("MessageHandlerSchedulerInitializer")
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler messageHandlerScheduler;

@Bean("MessageHandlerSchedulerInitializer")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler messageHandlerSchedulerInitializer(){
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("LmSolaceMessageHandler");
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
}```
````

Error
**Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:**

┌─────┐
|  myMessageHandler (field private org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ...myMessageHandler)
└─────┘

Please help me on above issue

Thanks
Bhushan

Comment: i saw some other question ..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036903/spring-boot-application-fails-to-start-after-upgrading-to-2-6-0-due-to-circular

and found solution like put
**spring.main.allow-circular-references=true**

But not working for me....

Comment: how are you setting the properties ? through application.properties or is it a docker, or spring cloud, zookeeper or kubernetes configmap