# spring boot circular dependency happening with field and setter injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17, spring-3

I've read that to resolve circular dependency we should either use setter or field injection.
I tried both but I still have the same issue. I am using spring boot app : java17/spring 3.1.5.

1. Setter injection

BeanA

```
@Component
public class BeanA {

    BeanA() {
        System.out.println("BeanA constructor called !!!");
    }

    private BeanB beanB;

    @Autowired
    public void setBeanB(BeanB beanB) {
        System.out.println("Setting property beanB of BeanA instance");
        this.beanB = beanB;
    }
}
```

BeanB

```
@Component
public class BeanB {

BeanB() {
        System.out.println("BeanB constructor called !!!");
    }

    private BeanA beanA;

    @Autowired
    public void setBeanA(BeanA beanA) {
        System.out.println("Setting property beanA of BeanB instance");
        this.beanA = beanA;
    }
}
```

2. Field injection

BeanA

```
@Component
public class BeanA {

    @Autowired
    BeanB beanB;

    BeanA(){
//        System.out.println("beanA init!");
    }
}
```

Bean B

```
@Component
public class BeanB {

    @Autowired
    BeanA beanA;

    BeanB(){
        System.out.println("beanB init!");
    }
}
```

for both examples I get the following error

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  beanA
↑     ↓
|  beanB
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

below is the hierarchy of the app

```
com.demo.example
MainApp.java
setterInjection
..beanA
..beanB
fieldIjection
..beanA
..beanB
```

Comment: The answer is literally in the error message you posted: "Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. (...) As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting `spring.main.allow-circular-references` to true."

Comment: yes but that's not what everybody is saying on the internet. They litteraly say we should get no error if we use setter/field injection

Comment: Well, either the internet is wrong (surprise!) or you've misunderstood something.

Comment: You need to tell spring to allow circular dependencies - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036903/spring-boot-application-fails-to-start-after-upgrading-to-2-6-0-due-to-circular) should help. Now that it's allowed, keep in mind that you are not resolving the circular dependency by using fields/setters, you are merely circumventing it.

Comment: Apparently it's related to spring version, in older spring versions switching to setter/field injection would result in"circumventing " it?

Comment: @clorzs Yes in older versions that would be enough, as they did not prohibit it by default. In newer ones you need to allow it, before proceeding to "circumvent" with field/setter injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding following values in application.properties/yaml file:
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true